# Upgrading from core 1.0 to 2.2

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, migration

I'm trying to upgrade a huge project from core 1.0 to 2.2. I decided to do this through creating new project from scratch and just moving there all files from existing project. I did that, fixed all errors related to usage of inappropriate packages, old syntax etc.

Now I get the login page when running project, but after actually logging in i get `TypeLoadException`.

> "TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'."

Comment: Did you  updated the references to the newer asseblies/packages?